# How do I change what is printed depending on the user's input

Tags: c, string

I can't seem to figure out how to change what is printed to the Terminal based on the user's input. No matter what I do, the Terminal keeps printing "Okay. First Question.". How would I change this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main(){
    char Q0real[]="Yes",Q0ans[3];
    printf("Welcome to my game v0.1\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("Just answer the questions to win!\n");
    sleep(3);
    printf("Do you understand? (Yes/Yes)\n");
    scanf("%s",&Q0ans);
    int result;
    result=strcmp(Q0real,Q0ans);
    if(result==0){
        printf("Okay. First Question.\n\n");
        sleep(2);
    }else if(result!=0){
        printf("GET OUT, RIGHT NOW. LEAVE.");
        sleep(10);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&Q0ans);` should be `scanf("%s",Q0ans);` and `Q0ans[3]` should be `Q0ans[4]` at least if you want it to be able to hold the word "Yes". You need to allow enough space for the word and the terminating 0. You can also supply a maximum length in the format string to avoid buffer overflows. Assuming you made space for 4 characters, `scanf("%3s",Q0ans);`

Comment: Don't even allocate 4 characters, but 40, and restrict the entry length with `scanf("%39s", Q0ans);`. It's rarely necessary to be scrupulously tight with a buffer size, and when it's exactly the right size and the user types just one letter too many, that letter will be picked up by the following entry, and *that* won't be accepted either.